# use python pandas convert csv to html

Tags: python, html, csv, pandas

I have a csv file and need to convert to html format. I know python pandas can do it with `DataFormat.to_html()`, but could not figure out what value to put in the (). I have:

```
pd.DataFrame.to_html(class=myfile.csv)
```

but got issue with it.
Anyone has idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to put there dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv")
df.to_html('your_file.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put path where you want to save file including file name.
Example:
DF.to_html ("C:/desktop/test.html")